# How to change the opacity of dots on overlap in d3js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, visualization

I have a set of points. which I plot using d3. MAny times some of the points tend to overlap. I need to change the opacity of the dot for points which are overlapped a lot. For example, dots having the same position (x,y) should be much darker than non-overlapped dots. I am not sure how to do that. The following is my current code for scatter plot of points.

```
svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



    var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")   
                    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
                    .style("opacity", 0);

    x.domain(d3.extent(gdata, function(d) {  return d[xdata]; })).nice();
    y.domain(d3.extent(gdata, function(d) { return d[ydata]; })).nice();

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("x", width)
        .attr("y", -6)
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("sum("+xdata+")");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("sum("+ydata+")")

    svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .data(gdata)
        .enter().append("svg:circle")


        .on("click", function(d) {
             console.log(d);
             var ele = d3.select(this);
             console.log("the ele is ",ele);
             clickdot(d,ele) ;// Cannot use this as of now
        })

        .on("mouseover", function(d) {   
            console.log("entered mouseover event");   
            tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);      
            console.log("the object is d" ,d );
            tooltip.html(d[xdata] + " " + d[ydata])  
              .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
              .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        })                  

        .on("mouseout", function(d) { 
            console.log("entered mouseout event");      
            tooltip.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);   
        })
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("r", 5.5)
        .attr("opacity", "0.6") // --> this should be changed. I guess
        .attr("stroke", "")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[xdata]); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[ydata]); })
        .style("fill", function(d) { 
            if (d.pid == $('#id').val()) {
                   return "red" ;
            }
            return "#1f77b4" ; //blue coloe 
        });            
}
```

I guess I need to add some condition on opacity. Not sure how to specify that.

Comment: Sounds like your question is not quite "how to set opacity based on overlap", but "given a circle, how to calculate how many other circles overlap it and by what amount." Setting the opacity is cake. Calculating overlap is complicated. It's too broad a question for SO. You can do some research (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) or [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16927/efficient-algorithm-to-find-overlapping-circles-of-various-sizes)) and consider whether it's worth implementing.

Comment: I already have coordinates which can tell me the dots are overlapping. All I need to do is if the counter for a given coordinate is higher so will be its opacity. Not sure, if this seems like a daunting task.

Comment: If you already know the number of overlaps per dot, then you can just use a `d3.scale.linear` (or maybe non-linear) with `domain([0, /* max number of overlaps in the dataset*/])` and `range([.5, 1])`. Then you set the opacity with something `.attr("opacity", function(d) { return opacityScale(d.num_overlaps); })`.

Answer (score 0):

To compute the count you can use crossfilter : https://github.com/square/crossfilter. 
Declare a dimension that provides x,y and count for that x,y pair and use this as your data source.
Then you might be stuck with one circle per overlapping set. It really depends on what you are trying to show to the user.